# Can the Tenseigan be transplanted?

Tags: naruto

Is the Tenseigan able to get transplanted? I've tried Googling it but it did not give me the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically speaking, the *Tenseigan* should **NOT** be able to get transplanted, as long as the receiver isn't of the Otsutsuki.

According to a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-the-Hyuga-are-descendants-of-the-Ootsuki-and-posses-the-byakugan-why-is-no-one-ever-shown-to-awaken-the-Tenseigan#:%7E:text=The%20Tenseigan%20is%20a%20dojutsu,of%20an%20Otsusuki%20clan%20member.&text=And%20so%20the-,The%20Tenseigan%20is%20a%20dojutsu%20that%20can%20be%20awakened%20by,of%20an%20Otsusuki%20clan%20member.) page I found:

> The Tenseigan is a dojutsu that can be awakened by a combination of a Byakugan and the Chakra of an Otsusuki clan member. The Tenseigan is a dojutsu that can be awakened by a combination of a Byakugan and the Chakra of an Otsusuki clan member.

Considering the fact that Tenseigan can only be awakened when a Byakugan is tied to the chakra of an Otsutsuki Clan member, it should not be able to get transplanted because once taken out of the eyes, it is no longer tied to Otsutsuki chakra of any sort. This is assuming the receiver of the *Tenseigan* isn't Otsutsuki themselves.

For more information on the Tenseigan, please check out *[this](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tenseigan)* link.

Answer (score 1):

So, Based on this theory I can say that a **Tenseigan** cannot be transplanted I will tell you why If you watched the movie (The Last: Naruto the movie) where he meets Toneri Otsusuki who is a generation of Hamura where he kidnaps Hinata. Yes, Over there the plot mention as follows:

*The Hyuga Clan revealed to be descended from Hamura's kin who remained on Earth, Toneri had transplanted Hanabi's eyes into himself so he can acquire the Tenseigan (転生眼, lit. "Reincarnation Eye") created from his ancestors' sealed eyes while proposing to Hinata.*

So in theory a **Tenseigan** can gain the power if the person who wants to require it must be a descendent of a Hamura and in order to complete the Tenseigan they have to acquire a **Byakugan** from the Hyuga Clan since they are Byakugan users and it will take several days to mature it.

In Conclusion, A Tenseignan cannot be transplanted and even if they do it might not activate due to these facts.

Answer (score 0):

**It cannot** be transferred like the sharingan. Like the sharingan it can be awakened.

**Tenseigan can be acquired when an Ōtsutsuki is implanted with the Byakugan of a Hyūga: this combination of the two clans' chakra transforms the Byakugan into Tenseigan**

Although the sharingan and byakugan is placed in the same category of dojutsu

https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tenseigan

[image: Tenseigan]